# Triggering a div animation by scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

Im working on a horizontal-scrolling website. The website has a large background image (5000px width). Now, I have div's with content that are currently at display:hidden. I know how to fade them in, but I need them to enter into view dynamically as I scroll to the right, and I would like to trigger these divs using percentages.

Example: user begins to scroll right, once they hit 20% width, first div enters into view (from right). User then continues to scroll until they hit 40% width, first div animates away (to the left) and next div enters into view (from right).

Any idea how I can accomplish this with jQuery??

Here is a bit of code... At the moment I have links that trigger some basic animations. But nothing for manual scrolling. Oh and im using this great pluggin called ScrollTo for the percentages.

HTML

```
<div id="eat" class="sections">
 <div class="content">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="see" class="sections">
 <div class="content">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="meet" class="sections">
 <div class="content">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="find" class="sections">
 <div class="content">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="background">
 <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="" id="bg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sections {position:absolute; right: 0; width:700px; height: 100%; min-height: 650px; z-index: 10; background-color: rgb(0,0,0);}
#drink, #eat, #see, #meet, #find {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.content {margin: 20px; padding: 0px; outline: 1px solid red;}
h1 {color:#FFF; margin: 10em auto 0px auto;}
#background {height:103%; min-height: 670px; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: 9;}
#background img#bg {height: 100%; min-height: 650px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

JS

```
$("document").ready(function() {

$('#link1').click(function(){
    $('#background').scrollTo('20%', 1500);
        var div = $('#drink');
        div.animate({right: $(window).width()/2 - div.outerWidth()/2}, {duration: 1500, queue: false}, function() {
        });
        $('#logo, #eat, #see, #meet, #find').fadeOut(500);          
        $('#drink').fadeIn(500);
});

$('#link2').click(function(){
    $('#background').scrollTo('40%', 1500);
        var div = $('#eat');
        div.animate({right: $(window).width()/2 - div.outerWidth()/2}, {duration: 1500, queue: false}, function() {
        });
        $('#logo, #drink, #see, #meet, #find').fadeOut(500);
        $('#eat').fadeIn(500);
});

$('#link3').click(function(){
    $('#background').scrollTo('60%', 1500);
        var div = $('#see');
        div.animate({right: $(window).width()/2 - div.outerWidth()/2}, {duration: 1500, queue: false}, function() {
        });
        $('#logo, #drink, #eat, #meet, #find').fadeOut(500);                
        $('#see').fadeIn(500);
});

$('#link4').click(function(){
    $('#background').scrollTo('80%', 1500);
        var div = $('#meet');
        div.animate({right: $(window).width()/2 - div.outerWidth()/2}, {duration: 1500, queue: false}, function() {
        });
        $('#logo, #drink, #eat, #see, #find').fadeOut(500);
        $('#meet').fadeIn(500);
});

$('#link5').click(function(){
    $('#background').scrollTo('100%', 1500);
        var div = $('#find');
        div.animate({right: $(window).width()/2 - div.outerWidth()/2}, {duration: 1500, queue: false}, function() {
        });
        $('#logo, #drink, #eat, #see, #meet').fadeOut(500);
        $('#find').fadeIn(500);
});

});
```

Comment: It's actually quite simple, get the window width and figure out how much 100% is, then the rest of the percentages should be straigh forward to get in pixels, and compare that to how much is scrolled in pixels etc. But without any code or even a try, noone is going to write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the scroll event, then do your calculations based on `scrollLeft()` like this:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  //do the math
  console.log( $(this).scrollLeft() );
});
```

Comment: Does this still work if im using this ScrollTo pluggin? I've attached some code to show how it's being treated.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event in jQuery. Here is another answer that gives you an idea of how you could track left and right scrolling. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308435/53007